# Does Spark read into CPU-RAM before GPU-RAM?

Tags: apache-spark, gpu, nvidia

Does Spark read a data frame directly into the GPU's RAM or must it first be written to the standard RAM?

In watching some 2018 Databricks talks, they made it sound like that CUDA had to pass the object through the regular CPU to the GPU's memory.

AKA does my regular RAM have to match the size of my GPU RAM?

Comment: CUDA kernels have to read through RAM, so yes you need RAM. Does it need to match to GPU not necessarily. Don't know about spark though

Comment: Are you advocating for pushing through regular RAM in small pieces?

Comment: Spark doesn't have native support for GPUs yet

Comment: Ah I thought that was coming in 3.0

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax yeah. Not a good idea though.

Comment: ah, yeah i guess i would only be using gpu in keras, not spark